# setNeedsLayout relayouts the cell only after is has been displayed

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a table view with cells, which sometimes have an optional UI element, and sometimes it has to be removed.
Depending on the element, label is resized.

When cell is initialised, it is narrower than it will be later on. When I set data into the label, this code is called from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```c
if (someFlag) {
    // This causes layout to be invalidated
    [flagIcon removeFromSuperview];
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
}
```

After that, cell is returned to the table view, and it is displayed. However, the text label at that point has adjusted its width, but not height. Height gets adjusted after a second or so, and the jerk is clearly visible when all cells are already displayed.

Important note, this is only during initial creation of the first few cells. Once they are reused, all is fine, as optional view is removed and label is already sized correctly form previous usages.

Why isn't cell re-layouted fully after `setNeedsLayout` but before it has been displayed? Shouldn't UIKit check invalid layouts before display?

If I do

```c
if (someFlag) {
    [flagIcon removeFromSuperview];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

all gets adjusted at once, but it seems like an incorrect way to write code, I feel I am missing something else.

---

Some more code on how cell is created:

```c
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ProfileCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    [cell setData:model.items[indexPath.row] forMyself:YES];
    return cell;
}

// And in ProfileCell:
- (void)setData:(Entity *)data forMyself:(BOOL)forMe
{
    self.entity = data;

    [self.problematicLabel setText:data.attributedBody];
    // Set data in other subviews as well

    if (forMe) {
        // This causes layouts to be invalidated, and problematicLabel should resize
        [self.reportButton removeFromSuperview];
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

Also, if it matters, in storyboard cell looks like this, with optional constraint taking over once flag icon is removed:
[image: Constraints in the storyboard]

Comment: Are you using stock `UITableViewCell`s or custom cells?

Comment: Can you please add all cellForRowAtIndexPath: method?
I think I will be able to help you if you do so :)

Comment: OK. Here is what I have learnt (painfully) working with `UITableViews`. The `drawRect` method of `UITableView`s is not called 'always'. I suppose you are reusing cells with `dequeueReusableCellWithCellIdentifier`. One thing you could try to do is place a `[yourCell drawRect]` in the `willDisplayCell` method. This method is always called whenever a cell is about to move to visible bounds. Also `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay` are taxing methods on memory, in cells with lots of content.

Comment: @Refael.S I have added the code, although there isn't much in it, I'm pretty sure. Also added how it looks in the storyboard.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer thanks, but calling `drawRect` is a much worse hack than `layoutIfNeeded`. Also, the problem is for new cells, not for reused ones.

Comment: I see. Let me get back to you.

Comment: @coverback Did you find any good solution? I am facing the same issue. What solution you used?

Comment: @Geek No, I am still calling `layoutIfNeeded` as in the question text.

Comment: @coverback But has it solved your issue? You still see that jerk?

Comment: @coverback I get that jerk even with `layoutIfNeeded`. Can you show me your full code for `UITableView`?

Comment: @Geek there isn't anything else to show, code is very simple. Maybe you should create a question of your own.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46517/discussion-between-geek-and-coverback)

Comment: manually forcing the size by hardcoding it in willDisplayCell was the only way I could fix this issue, if. you have a view that has a constant and a dynamic part then you can get the view,width and subtract the constant from it to calculate the variable one manually!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that calling `layoutIfNeeded` seems wrong, even though it works in your case. But I doubt that you're missing something. Although I haven't done any research on the manner, in my experience using Auto Layout in table cells *that undergo a dynamic layout* is a bit buggy. That is, I see herky jerky layouts when removing or adding subviews to cells at runtime.

If you're looking for an alternative strategy (using Auto Layout), you could subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `layoutSubviews`. The custom table cell could expose a flag in its public API that could be set in the implementation of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. The cell's `layoutSubviews` method would use the flag to determine whether or not it should include the optional UI element. I make no guarantees that this will eliminate the problem however.

A second strategy is to design two separate cell types and swap between the two in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as necessary.

Comment: I think trying to impact layouting is more heavy and complicated than just calling `layoutIfNeeded`. I have thought about two cells, but maintaining two almost exactly same views is more error-prone in the future.

Comment: It does indeed seem that nothing else is to be done here, so I'll be marking your answer as accepted. I didn't find anything else to fix this, nor any of the other suggestions worked.

Answer (score 0):

You've added additional code to the question, so I have another suggestion. In the cell's `setData:forMyself:` method, try calling `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` instead of `layoutIfNeeded`.

Comment: Doesn't change anything. In fact, when printing out `needsUpdateConstraints` it is already `YES`, and same for layout, because removing from superview already invalidated it.

Comment: So, in original code, `[cell setNeedsLayout]` is redundant, I put it there to avoid answers "add `setNeedsLayout`".